# Adding text to the left margin

Tags: vimscript

Is there an easy way to add text to the left margin of a vim document (to the left of the line numbers)?

I know that it is possible to do because plugins such as vim-signature do it, but I am curious how this is done, and what the easiest way to do it would be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think what you are referring to is called a sign by vim.

Adding a sign seems to be a two-step process. First you define what it looks like, then you place it where you want.

The basic syntax to define a sign is:

```
:sign define {name} {argument}...
```

Where `{argument}...` is a series of arguments that you can choose :

- `icon=` full path to an icon
- `linehl=` highlighting group for the whole line on which you will place the sign
- `text=` text to display if there's no icon or you run vim in a terminal
- `texthl=` highlighting group for `text`

To place your sign, once you've defined it :

```
:sign place {id} line={lnum} name={name} file={fname}
```

- `{id}` is an arbitrary number which will allow you to manipulate the sign later
- `{lnum}` and `{fname}` are respectively the line number and the file in which you want to place your sign
- `{name}` is the name of your sign

To list your signs and see their attributes:

```
:sign list
```

To remove a sign :

```
:sign unplace {id} file={fname}
```

---

**Usage example**

```
:sign define mysign text=>> texthl=Search
```

... defines the sign `mysign`, which will display the text `>>` with the colors from the highlighting group `Search`.

Now, assuming you're editing the file `/tmp/foo`, you can place your sign on its 10th line with:

```
:sign place 9999 line=10 name=mysign file=/tmp/foo
```

Here the id 9999 was chosen.

Finally, to remove the sign you just placed:

```
:sign unplace 9999 file=/tmp/foo
```

There are many other ways to define, place and unplace a sign.
For more information, see:

```
:help sign-commands
:help :sign-define
:help :sign-undefine
:help :sign-list
:help :sign-place
:help :sign-unplace
:help :sign-place-list
:help :sign-jump
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for :)... I initially wanted to know for curiosity and also because I use vim-signature, and gitgutter for vim but they both use the sign column. I was wanting to see if I could add an extra sign column so that I could use the information from both plugins simultaneously, but it would appear that this is not possible. I did find that vim-signature has a flag you can set that helps with that. See the [issue I had opened here](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter/issues/289) which also has my solution and a link to the commit I made on my vimrc to use it.